# How can I add a Trigonometric expression in a polynomial expression in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm having a problem adding a trigonometrical expression in a polynomial expression.
Creating a Polynomial in `numpy` is quite easy, but adding a trigonometrical expression is troubling me.

The result must be something like:

```
f(x) = p(x) + k*cos(x),

'''
where:
p(x) is a polynomial expression;
k is a constant;
cos(x) is a trigonometrical expression.
'''
```

Anyone?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can easily implement it using numpy or without:
using numpy

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.polynomial import Polynomial

# f(x) = p(x) + k * np.cos(x)

p = Polynomial((1, 2, 3)) # --> 1 + 2 * x + 3 * x**2

def f(x):
    k = 2
    return p(x) + k * np.cos(x)

f(5)
```

output:

```
86.56732437092646
```

without numpy:

```
from math import cos
def p(x):
    return 1 + 2 * x + 3 * x**2

def f(x):
    return p(x) + 2 * cos(x)

f(5)
```

output:

```
86.56732437092646
```